# Where can I get historical stock data from different companies from the 70s to today

Tags: historical-data

I'm trying to calculate what a person would have earned if he invested all his savings into random stocks until retirement from 1975 to today.
Basically I just a need a set of stock market data that can be downloaded and processed by a programm (API, CSV, etc) and then be graphed with imaginary money to show the total gains after 65 years.
So where can I get such data? Just from a bunch of companies that had stock in the 70s.

Comment: Be careful of survivorship bias. There were a lot of companies around in the 1970s that no longer exist. If you select companies based somehow only on those still around today, you're going to have skewed results not representative of what you're trying to simulate.

Comment: Thanks, I hope they are still on yahoo though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Historical Data at Yahoo Finance.  I've seen some stocks there with data from the 60's.  It can be exported as a CSV file.